# Fuse ESB JPA Entity not persisting

Tags: jpa, jta, fuseesb

I have been attempting to us JPA to persist an entity in a simple Fuse ESB project, but I'm facing the problem that the entity never gets written to the the underlying database. The project is structured with the following three modules:

simple-datasource

simple-model

simple-service

The datasource is configured through blueprint and the datasource attached to jndi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

<bean id="simpleDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=yes)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xyz))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx)(PORT=1521)))" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />       
</bean>


<service ref="simpleDataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/simpleDataSource" />
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

The model defines a persistent unit inside persistence.xml file and references the datasource through jndi:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="simple-service-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/simpleDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <!-- list of the persistance classes -->
    <class>com.model.SimpleRow</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

The SimpleRow class uses JPA annotations:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "SIMPLE")
public class SimpleRow {

@Column(name = "simple_id")
private Long simpleId;

@Column(name = "simple_text", length =100)
private String simpleText;

public Long getSimpleId() {
    return simpleId;
}

public void setSimpleId(Long simpleId) {
    this.simpleId = simpleId;
}

public String getSimpleText() {
    return simpleText;
}

public void setSimpleText(String simpleText) {
    this.simpleText = simpleText;
}
```

}

I then inject the EntityManager into a service, again using blueprint and a reference to the simple-service-persistence-unit and specify that method level transaction demarcation should be used (as I've seen in all the examples):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.1.0"    xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.1.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
   http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.1.0   http://aries.apache.org/schemas/jpa/jpa_110.xsd">

<bean id="simpleService" class="com.service.SimpleServiceImpl">
    <jpa:context property="entityManager" unitname="simple-service-persistence-unit" />
    <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required" />
</bean>

<service ref="simpleService" interface="com.service.SimpleService" />
```

The simple service simply creates an entity and persists it using the EntityManager as follows:

```
public class SimpleServiceImpl implements SimpleService {

EntityManager entityManager;

    public void invokeSimpleService() {
    try {

        SimpleRow row = new SimpleRow();
        row.setSimpleText("Some simple text");
        entityManager.persist(row);
        System.out.println("Persisted row...");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    }

} ...
```

One final configuration which is relevant is the feature set which is as follows:

```
<feature dependency="true" version="${activemq.version}">activemq-camel</feature>
    <feature dependency="true" version="${camel.version}">camel-blueprint</feature>
    <feature dependency="true" version="${camel.version}">camel-core</feature>
    <feature dependency="true" version="${cxf.version}">cxf</feature>
    <feature dependency="true" version="${camel.version}">camel-cxf</feature>
    <feature dependency="true" version="${camel.version}">camel-jpa</feature>
    <feature dependency="true" version="1.0.1.fuse-71-047">transaction</feature>
    <feature dependency="true" version="${jpa.version}">jpa</feature>
    <feature dependency="true" version="${jndi.version}">jndi</feature>
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:net.sourceforge.serp/serp/1.13.1</bundle>
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:oracle/ojdbc/11.2.0.3</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.h2database/h2/1.3.167</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.company/simple-datasource/${project.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.company/simple-model/${project.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.company/simple-service/${project.version}</bundle>
```

I have verified that the datasource works correctly by injecting it as service into another module which uses it with a straight JDBC connection.

However, when invoke SimpleService.invokeSimpleService, the code executes, no exceptions are thrown but the write is not persisted on the database.

If I add a flush after the persist i.e.

```
entityManager.persist()
```

then the following error is thrown:

```
An error occurred: Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.
```

If I try and start the transaction explicitly, and remove the tx:transaction annotation on the service bean config, then it fails with the following error:

```
An error occurred: Transaction management is not available for container managed EntityManagers.
```

Other information that might be of relevance. The underlying EntityManager implementation is:

```
org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context.transaction.impl.JTAEntityManager
```

Also the list of installed aries components is:

```
[   7] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint Core     (1.0.1.fuse-71-047)
[   9] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Util (1.0.0)
[  10] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint CM  (1.0.1.fuse-71-047)
[  11] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Proxy API (1.0.0)
[  12] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Proxy Service (1.0.0)
[  13] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint API (1.0.1.fuse-71-047)
[  25] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Blueprint API (1.0.1.fuse-71-047)
[  30] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Blueprint Core (1.0.1.fuse-71-047)
[  33] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX API (1.0.1.fuse-71-047)
[  38] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Core (1.0.1.fuse-71-047)
[  75] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] Aries JPA Container Managed Contexts (1.0.0)
[  77] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   60] Apache Aries Transaction Enlisting JDBC Datasource (1.0.1.fuse-71-047)
[  81] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] Aries JPA Container API (1.0.0)
[ 100] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   60] Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint (1.0.1.fuse-71-047)
[ 118] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] Apache Aries JNDI API (1.0.0)
[ 125] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] Aries JPA Container (1.0.0)
[ 139] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] Apache Aries JNDI Core (1.0.0)
[ 144] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] Apache Aries JNDI Support for Legacy Runtimes (1.0.0)
[ 146] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] Apache Aries JNDI RMI Handler (1.0.0)
[ 168] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   60] Aries JPA Container blueprint integration for Aries blueprint (1.0.0)
[ 176] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] Apache Aries Transaction Manager (1.0.1.fuse-71-047)
[ 177] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] Apache Aries JNDI URL Handler (1.0.0)
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with this configuration, which follows most of the examples online?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly when using resource_local as the transaction type is appropriate in the persistence layer. However, modifying persistence.xml to use JTA and jta-data-source as follows fixed my issue:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="simple-service-persistence-unit"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    </provider>
    <!--non-jta-data-source>osgi:service/jdbc/simpleDataSource</non-jta-data-source-->      
    <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/simpleDataSource)</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.company.model.SimpleRow</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I suspect the reason is that the incorrect EntityManager is being used. Despite the fact that the openjpa persistence provider is being specified, blueprint is ultimately injecting the container EntityManager: org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context.transaction.impl.JTAEntityManager. This might be down to the fact that the openjpa implementations class isn't available to the service module in this case, and so defaults to the container implementation.